# React Router v4 move navbar to separat file

Tags: reactjs, react-router, navbar

I am currently trying to separate my navbar from the ReactDOM.render() function using react router v4. But how can I move a navbar to a separate file using the new react router v4 and a Link component?

My starting point of the application `client.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link} from 'react-router-dom';

import store from './store';

import NavBar from './components/NavBar.react';
import WelcomePage from './components/Pages/Welcome.react';
import LoginPage from './components/Pages/Login.react';

const app = document.getElementById('app');

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
      <Router>
        <div>
          <NavBar />

          <Route exact path="/" component={WelcomePage} />
          <Route path="/login" component={LoginPage} />
        </div>
      </Router>
  </Provider>, app);
```

My separated navbar file `NavBar.react.js`:

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Link } from 'react-router';

export default class NavBar extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
            <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
            <li><Link to="/login">Login</Link></li>
        </ul>

        <hr/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Running this code throws me the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in. Check the render method of `NavBar`.
at invariant (invariant.js:44)
at instantiateReactComponent (instantiateReactComponent.js:74)
at instantiateChild (ReactChildReconciler.js:44)
at ReactChildReconciler.js:71
at traverseAllChildrenImpl (traverseAllChildren.js:77)
at traverseAllChildren (traverseAllChildren.js:172)
at Object.instantiateChildren (ReactChildReconciler.js:70)
at ReactDOMComponent._reconcilerInstantiateChildren (ReactMultiChild.js:187)
at ReactDOMComponent.mountChildren (ReactMultiChild.js:226)
at ReactDOMComponent._createInitialChildren (ReactDOMComponent.js:697)
```

If I remove the line `<NavBar />` or move the JSX content of my NavBar to the `client.js` file, it works...

Until now I have just found some examples around the internet where people integrated their navbar into the ReactDOM.render() function.

Comment: did you fix that?

Comment: Yeah, actually importing the `Link` component from `react-router-dom` instead of `react-router` worked for me, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're importing Link from 'react'router' in your Navbar component. This will work if you've installed both "react-router" and "react-router-dom", but instead what you probably want to do is just `import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';` because it looks like you've already installed `react-router-dom`.